# Cakephp can not locate Lib/Error/AppExceptionRenderer

Tags: php, cakephp, exception, error-handling

I am trying to add custom exception renderer in cakephp 2.0.

Following the tutorials, I added this code to `core.php`

```
Configure::write('Exception', array(
    'handler' => 'ErrorHandler::handleException',
    'renderer' => 'AppExceptionRenderer',
    'log' => true
));
```

And AppExceptionRenderer class is located in `app/Lib/Error/AppExceptionRenderer.php`

However I get following error when exception happens.

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Class 'AppExceptionRenderer' not found in <b>/srv/cs-backend/cs-backend/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php</b> on line <b>121</b><br />
```

It looks like `App::uses` is not working well. But not quite sure. Please help.

Comment: Your `AppExceptionRenderer.php` doesn't contain any syntax error?

Comment: Sorry for late response @KuritaTakashi. It doesn't have any syntax error.

Comment: Hmm... What happens if you change your `AppExceptionRenderer` class to an empty subclass like a `class AppExceptionRenderer extends ExceptionRenderer {}`?

Comment: Sorry to waste your time. May I ask the version of CakePHP your are using? I want to know the full version number. I try to reproduce. It works fine at least 2.8.

Comment: I am using cakephp 2.4